# Goals > Overview Display Incorrect Counts

Tags: google-analytics

I've set up multiple Goal funnels - pretty much the same for all except for the first step in the flow. Below is one example. The Destination has "subpg=" because there's only one main Thank-you page, and depending on which page the form was completed, subpg will have value like subpg=consulting etc.

The flow: visitors must (required) visit the Consulting page first, then from there click on the form, and complete the form.

The thing is, for this example, my **Consulting goal funnel shows 0 form completion** - which is correct. However, **the Goals Overview page shows 2 form completion** for Consulting - which is not correct. Why?

[image: STEPS]
[image: GOAL COMPLETION = 0]

[image: GOAL COMPLETION = 2]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Required step" only affects funnel visualization, not the goal count itself, so that is likely your problem.